# Force Fields dont work

Tags: particles

Is it just at my version of 2.8 beta that force field wont affect anything or...I tried to do simple bals with added rigid body active and to apply force field or any field on it. It doesnt work.

Comment: Its working fine for me, I have the latest windows build. Maybe its a bug right now.

Comment: This is mac version i have.

Comment: it doesn´t work for me either. I use blender 3.4.
But I can not find any solution in the Internet...